# Is it possible to create a Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation from a dll and pdb?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I'd like to do code analysis using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, but compiling all our source code takes a while. Is there a way to use the already-compiled PDB and DLL files to get semantic and symbol data?

Comment: You can create a metadata reference, but you can't load source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, no. Neither the PDB nor DLL contain anything that could be used to reconstitute a Compilation in any way faster than you already could.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is true in theory (though it seems to be in practice). If time and effort is spent on compilation, then logically having the output should allow steps to be skipped when obtaining certain info (e.g. to which overload a particular method call refers).

Comment: I'm not saying it can't be done. There's just currently zero such support for it. And it'd be a *lot* of work to do.